# Javascript - Read script js only if radio is checked

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, variables

i'm stuck in a problem with a script js. This is the condition:

```
var stampProd = "?php $stampProd = '10001'; ?";

function valiAnswPos(){

                if (document.getElementById("positive").checked = true)
    {
    document.getElementById('add-to-cart-stamp').innerHTML = stampProd;
    }
```

The problem is that when i reload the page and this code is read immediately and i would like that php code was shown and read by only when i checked on radio button. Because when i reload the same page and go to options of my browser -> code html i read all code of script js and in this case i would that this script is read only i checked radio button.

This is possibile with called asynchronous or an if with PHP?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you want to not show the script in source code?

Comment: exatc man and show the script in source code only when i check on radio button...how i do?

Answer (score 0):

i got this solution for does trick for firebug for not source. because if it remove from source you will get js error.

```
  <div id="script">
<script>
var stampProd = "<?php $stampProd = '10001'; ?>";

function valiAnswPos(){

                if (document.getElementById("positive").checked = true)
    {
    document.getElementById('add-to-cart-stamp').innerHTML = stampProd;
    }
</script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('script').innerHTML="";

</script>
```

Comment: I tried man but unfortunately with the same result...now i try with recal the file js in my file with called asynchronous...otherwise other possibilities? Thanks.